# Recursively xv compress each file in multiple subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, compression

I have multiple directories and subdirectories, with files inside.
I would like to recursively compress each file in these (sub)directories with xv (xz -9ze -T0) which are not .xv files yet, without creating tar archives nor changing the folder tree.
Could you please tell me the 'magic' line to do that in bash? :)
Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the (vendor) documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Comment: The examples at the end of the [`find` command manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) ) are a good starting point. Learning how to adjust that to only find files, with/excluding  a certain file-name pattern should not be too difficult.

Comment: Something in line with `find . -type f -not -name '*.xz' -exec xz '{}' \;`